# Can not get sql query to run VBA and keep getting errors 3131 error in from clause and 3067 Query must contain at least one table or query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Trying to run a complicated left join on multiple columns and have results show up but won't run in VBA. I am a noob on this.

I have Tried adding brackets and removed `iif` statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'Pages ID ' & [p.id] & ', Model ' & '''' & [p.equipmentmodel] & '''' & ', S/Prefix ' & '''' & [p.equipmentserialprefix] & '''' & ', FuelTy ' & '''' & [p.equipmentfueltype] & '''' & ', EngMake ' & '''' & [p.EngineMake] & '''' & ', Engine ' & '''' & [p.enginemodel] & '''' & ', TraMake ' & '''' & [p.transmissionmake] & '''' & ', TraSeries ' & '''' & [p.transmissionseries] & '''' & ', TraModel ' & '''' & [p.transmissionModel] & '''' & ', TranType ' & '''' & [p.transmissiontype] & '''' & ', MastMake ' & '''' & [p.mastmake] & '''' & ', Mast ' & '''' & [p.mastmodel] & '''' & ', CtrlPnl ' & '''' & [p.controlpanel] & '''' & ', Volt ' & '''' & [p.voltage] & '''' & ', CtryCode ' & '''' & [p.countrycode] & '''' & ', Capacity ' & '''' & [p.capacity] & '''' & '; not on Model tbl.' AS Expr1") & _
("

FROM pgs_v AS p LEFT JOIN model AS M ON ([p.CAPACITY] = [M.CAPACITY]) AND ([p.VOLTAGE] = [M.VOLTAGE]) AND ([p.MASTMODEL] = [M.MASTMODEL]) AND ([p.TRANSMISSIONTYPE] = [M.TRANSMISSIONTYPE]) AND ([p.TRANSMISSIONSERIES] = [M.TRANSMISSIONSERIES]) AND ([p.EQUIPMENTSERIALPREFIX] = [M.EQUIPMENTSERIALPREFIX]) AND ([p.EQUIPMENTMODEL] = [M.EQUIPMENTMODEL]) AND ([p.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE] = [M.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE]) AND ([p.ENGINEMODEL] = [M.ENGINEMODEL]) AND ([p.ENGINEMAKE] = [M.ENGINEMAKE]) AND ([p.TRANSMISSIONMAKE] = [M.TRANSMISSIONMAKE]) AND ([p.TRANSMISSIONMODEL] = [M.TRANSMISSIONMODEL]) AND ([p.MASTMAKE] = [M.MASTMAKE]) AND ([p.CONTROLPANEL] = [M.CONTROLPANEL]) AND ([p.COUNTRYCODE] = [M.COUNTRYCODE])") & _
("

WHERE ((([p.ENGINEMAKE])<>'' And ([p.ENGINEMAKE]) Is Not Null) AND (([p.equipmentmodel])<>'' And ([p.equipmentmodel]) Is Not Null) AND (([p.equipmentserialprefix])<>'' And ([p.equipmentserialprefix]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.EQUIPMENTMODEL]) Is Null) AND (([p.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE])<>'' And ([p.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE]) Is Not Null) AND (([p.ENGINEMODEL])<>'' And ([p.ENGINEMODEL]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE]) Is Null)") & _
("

AND (([M.EQUIPMENTSERIALPREFIX]) Is Null) AND (([M.ENGINEMODEL]) Is Null) AND (([M.ENGINEMAKE]) Is Null) AND (([p.TRANSMISSIONMAKE])<>'' And ([p.TRANSMISSIONMAKE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.TRANSMISSIONMAKE]) Is Null) AND (([p.TRANSMISSIONSERIES])<>'' And ([p.TRANSMISSIONSERIES]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.TRANSMISSIONSERIES]) Is Null) AND (([p.TRANSMISSIONMODEL])<>'' And ([p.TRANSMISSIONMODEL]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.TRANSMISSIONMODEL]) Is Null) AND (([p.TRANSMISSIONTYPE])<>'' And ([p.TRANSMISSIONTYPE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.TRANSMISSIONTYPE]) Is Null) AND (([p.MASTMAKE])<>'' And ([p.MASTMAKE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.MASTMAKE]) Is Null) AND (([p.MASTMODEL])<>'' And") & _
 ("

 ([p.MASTMODEL]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.MASTMODEL]) Is Null) AND (([p.CONTROLPANEL])<>'' And ([p.CONTROLPANEL]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.CONTROLPANEL]) Is Null) AND (([p.VOLTAGE])<>'' And ([p.VOLTAGE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.VOLTAGE]) Is Null) AND (([p.COUNTRYCODE])<>'' And ([p.COUNTRYCODE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.COUNTRYCODE]) Is Null) AND (([p.CAPACITY])<>'' And ([p.CAPACITY]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.CAPACITY]) Is Null))")
```

Comment: hey there, are FuelTy , EngMake  etc, variables inside the vba project or fields on your query table? , because it could be an error in the string construction of your query

Comment: They are text that refers to the column as this is a validator query so I added abbreviated field names as text and then the actual field results so it is easier to see what column it is for. So 'Pages ID ' & [p.id];  Pages Id is text and then p.id is the column.

Comment: I can usually get the queries to work if they are on one line but when I break them up into multiple lines is when I have issues usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the use of of parentheses ("a")&("b") isn't necessary, you could use a single "a" & "b" to concatenate strings and "a" & _ "b" to  join lines of code, try this to construct your query

```
Sub JoinQueryString()
Dim SqlQuery As String
SqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT 'Pages ID ' & [p.id] & ', Model ' & '''' & [p.equipmentmodel] & '''' & ', S/Prefix ' & '''' & [p.equipmentserialprefix] & '''' & ', FuelTy ' & '''' & [p.equipmentfueltype] & '''' & ', EngMake ' & '''' & [p.EngineMake] & '''' & ', Engine ' & '''' & [p.enginemodel] & '''' & ', TraMake ' & '''' & [p.transmissionmake] & '''' & ', TraSeries ' & '''' & [p.transmissionseries] & '''' & ', TraModel ' & '''' & [p.transmissionModel] & '''' & ', TranType ' & '''' & [p.transmissiontype] & '''' & ', MastMake ' & '''' & [p.mastmake] & '''' & ', Mast ' & '''' & [p.mastmodel] & '''' & ', CtrlPnl ' & '''' & [p.controlpanel] & '''' & ', Volt ' & '''' & [p.voltage] & '''' & ', CtryCode ' & '''' & [p.countrycode] & '''' & ', Capacity ' & '''' & [p.capacity] & '''' & '; not on Model tbl.' AS Expr1" & _
" FROM pgs_v AS p LEFT JOIN model AS M ON ([p.CAPACITY] = [M.CAPACITY]) AND ([p.VOLTAGE] = [M.VOLTAGE]) AND ([p.MASTMODEL] = [M.MASTMODEL]) AND ([p.TRANSMISSIONTYPE] = [M.TRANSMISSIONTYPE]) AND ([p.TRANSMISSIONSERIES] = [M.TRANSMISSIONSERIES]) AND ([p.EQUIPMENTSERIALPREFIX] = [M.EQUIPMENTSERIALPREFIX]) AND ([p.EQUIPMENTMODEL] = [M.EQUIPMENTMODEL]) AND ([p.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE] = [M.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE]) AND ([p.ENGINEMODEL] = [M.ENGINEMODEL]) AND ([p.ENGINEMAKE] = [M.ENGINEMAKE]) AND ([p.TRANSMISSIONMAKE] = [M.TRANSMISSIONMAKE]) AND ([p.TRANSMISSIONMODEL] = [M.TRANSMISSIONMODEL]) AND ([p.MASTMAKE] = [M.MASTMAKE]) AND ([p.CONTROLPANEL] = [M.CONTROLPANEL]) AND ([p.COUNTRYCODE] = [M.COUNTRYCODE]) " & _
" WHERE ((([p.ENGINEMAKE])<>'' And ([p.ENGINEMAKE]) Is Not Null) AND (([p.equipmentmodel])<>'' And ([p.equipmentmodel]) Is Not Null) AND (([p.equipmentserialprefix])<>'' And ([p.equipmentserialprefix]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.EQUIPMENTMODEL]) Is Null) AND (([p.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE])<>'' And ([p.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE]) Is Not Null) AND (([p.ENGINEMODEL])<>'' And ([p.ENGINEMODEL]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.EQUIPMENTFUELTYPE]) Is Null) " & _
" AND (([M.EQUIPMENTSERIALPREFIX]) Is Null) AND (([M.ENGINEMODEL]) Is Null) AND (([M.ENGINEMAKE]) Is Null) AND (([p.TRANSMISSIONMAKE])<>'' And ([p.TRANSMISSIONMAKE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.TRANSMISSIONMAKE]) Is Null) AND (([p.TRANSMISSIONSERIES])<>'' And ([p.TRANSMISSIONSERIES]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.TRANSMISSIONSERIES]) Is Null) AND (([p.TRANSMISSIONMODEL])<>'' And ([p.TRANSMISSIONMODEL]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.TRANSMISSIONMODEL]) Is Null) AND (([p.TRANSMISSIONTYPE])<>'' And ([p.TRANSMISSIONTYPE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.TRANSMISSIONTYPE]) Is Null) AND (([p.MASTMAKE])<>'' And ([p.MASTMAKE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.MASTMAKE]) Is Null) AND (([p.MASTMODEL])<>'' AND " & _
" ([p.MASTMODEL]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.MASTMODEL]) Is Null) AND (([p.CONTROLPANEL])<>'' And ([p.CONTROLPANEL]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.CONTROLPANEL]) Is Null) AND (([p.VOLTAGE])<>'' And ([p.VOLTAGE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.VOLTAGE]) Is Null) AND (([p.COUNTRYCODE])<>'' And ([p.COUNTRYCODE]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.COUNTRYCODE]) Is Null) AND (([p.CAPACITY])<>'' And ([p.CAPACITY]) Is Not Null) AND (([M.CAPACITY]) Is Null))"
Debug.Print SqlQuery
End Sub
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much! I had a feeling it was something small but im a noob to vba.